# Python Find the index of value in sequence given the condition

Tags: python, while-loop, fibonacci

I have this problem but don't know where to start. The only thing I have in my mind is Fibonacci numbers and for loop (but don't know how to apply). It looks like Fibonacci but the first terms are different.

> We have a sequence beginning with `a` then `a+b`. The 3rd number is
> `a+b+a`, the 4th one is `a+b+a+a+b`. Which means that a number is
> equal to the sum of 2 previous terms. (except the two first terms).
>
> We need to find the index of the number given that the number is
> exactly 100k. `a` and `b` are picked randomly. The program has to end by print(a,b,index)

So my problem is, I don't know how to choose `a` and `b` which can satisfy the 100k condition. For example:

> If `a == 35k` and `b == 20k`, then the sequence would be like this:
> `35k, 55k, 90k, 145k` and no 100k in the sequence.

So how to deal with this problem? Really appreciate!!

Comment: Do you need to create a function that can find the index given a and b? Or do you need to find al of the combinations of a,b, and the index that satisfy your problem?

Comment: You cannot satisfy that ``f[n] = 100k`` for any ``a`` and ``b``. Only for some specific values...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: this is a correction over my last answer**

First write the difference equation according to the described conditions:

```
f[0] = a
f[1] = a + b
f[2] = f[1] + f[0] 
     = 2a + b = a + b + a
f[3] = f[2] + f[1] = f[1] + f[0] + f[1] 
     = 3a + 2b
     = a + b + a + a + b
f[4] = f[3] + f[2]
     = 3a + 2b + 2a + b = 5a + 3b
f[5] = f[4] + f[3]
     = 5a + 3b + 3a + 2b = 8a + 5b
f[6] = f[5] + f[4] 
     = 8a + 5b + 5a + 3b = 13a + 8b
...
f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2]
```

We can actually simplify this problem if we separate a and b:

```
f_a[n] = a*(f[n-1] + f[n-2]) with f[0] = 1 and f[1] = 1
f_b[n] = b*(f[n-1] + f[n-2]) with f[0] = 0 and f[1] = 1
```

Now, if we calculate the solution to the diference equation we should obtain the following assuming that `s=sqrt(5)` that n \in N (is a natural number):

```
w1a = ((1+s)/2)ˆ{n+1}
w2a = ((1-s)/2)ˆ{n+1}
w1b = ((1+s)/2)ˆn
w2b = ((1-s)/2)ˆn
f_a[n] = (1/s) * [w1a - w2a] * a
f_b[n] = (1/s) * [w1b - w2b] * b
```

Simplifying:

```
l = (1+s)/2
g = (1-s)/2
f[n] = f_a[n] + f_b[n]
     = (1/s) * [lˆn(al+b) - gˆn(ag+b)]
```

You can find more info on how to solve diference equations here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob07.pdf

You can implement these equations in a Python function to obtain any value of this function.

```py
from math import sqrt
def f(n, a, b):
    s = sqrt(5)
    l = (1+s)/2
    g = (1-s)/2
    fn = (1/s) * ((a*l + b) * (l**n) - (a*g + b) * (g**n))
    
    return int(round(fn, 0))
```

**Searching for the index iteratively**

You may now find the n which solves this equation for a particular f(n) if you apply the logarithmic function (see the section below). However, if time complexity is not an issue for you, and given that f[n] grows exponentially for n (meaning that you will not need to search much until 100k is reached or surpassed), you may also simply find the `n` which gives `f[n]` for a given `a` and `b` by doing the following search:

```
def search_index(a, b, value):
  n = 0 
  while(True):
    fn = f(n, a, b)
    if fn == value:
      return n
    elif fn > value:
      return -1
    else:
      n += 1

def brute_search(range_a, range_b, value):
    for a in range(range_a + 1):
        for b in range(range_b + 1):
            if (a == 0) and (b == 0): 
                a = 1
            res = search_index(a, b, value)
            if res != -1:
                return a, b, res
    return -1

brute_search(1000, 1000, 100000)
>>> (80, 565, 12) # a = 80, b = 565 and n = 12
```

Through this (quite bad) method we find that for `a=80` and `b=565`, `n=12` will return `f_n = 100k`. If you would like to find all possible solutions for a range of values of `a` and `b`, you can modify `brute_search` in the following way:

```
def brute_search_many_solutions(range_a, range_b, value):
    solutions = []
    for a in range(range_a + 1):
        for b in range(range_b + 1):
            if (a == 0) and (b == 0): 
                a = 1
            res = search_index(a, b, value)
            if res != -1:
                solutions.append((a, b, res))
    return solutions
```

**Analytical solution**

Transforming the previous diference equation `f_n` so that now `n` is a function of `a`, `b` and `f_n` we obtain:

```
n \aprox log((f_n * s) / (a * l + b)) / log(l)
```

This result is an approximation, which may guide your search. You can use it in the following way:

```
def find_n(a, b, value):
    s = sqrt(5)
    l = (1+s)/2
    g = (1-s)/2
    return int(round(log(value * s / (a * l + b)) / log(l), 0))

def search(a, b, value):
    n = find_n(a, b, value)
    sol = f(n, a, b)
    if sol == value:
        return(a, b, n)
    elif sol > value:
        for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
            sol = f(i, a, b)
            if sol == value:
                return(a, b, i)
            elif sol < value:
                return(-1, 'no solution exits for a={} and b={}'.format(a, b))
    else: # this should probably never be reached as find_n should 
          # provide an upper bound. But I still need to prove it
        i = n
        while(sol < value):
            i += 1
            sol = f(i, a, b)
            if sol == value:
                return(a, b, i)
            elif sol > value:
                return(-1, 'no solution exits for a={} and b={}'.format(a, b))

search(80, 565, 100000)
>>> (80, 565, 12) # a = 80, b = 565 and n = 12
```

NOTE: I would have loved to use mathematical notation here with LaTeX, but unfortunately I did not find an easy way to do it... Likely, this question would fit better Stack Exchange, than Stack overflow.

Comment: I don't think that you can generalize f[n] = (n-1)a + (n-2)b. For example, f[5] should be 5a + 3b, which does not comply with your assertion.

Comment: You are right. I fixed this by calculating the full solution to the differential equation. But did not solve in function of n for any ``a`` and ``b``, since it was not clear in the specification of the problem whether these values are given or not.

Comment: Could you apply your equation with some example values? I am able to follow your steps but can't really see how your conclusion solves the problem.

Comment: If you run ``f(12, 80, 565)`` with ``n=12`` ``a=80`` and ``b=565``, then you obtain ``f[n]=100k``. I am still deriving the full analytical expression to obtain ``n`` for any ``a`` and ``b``. However, there might be a way to simply implement the diference equation and search for the correct index... What puzzles me is this part of the question: "a and b are picked randomly"